# Struggling with the razor select helper

Tags: asp.net-core, select, razor, .net-core, selected

While trying out ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC with razor, I had a hell of a struggle with this, and I'm still not sure why my prior attempts -- which I thought mimicked what I saw here on stackoverflow -- did not display the selected option, but here's one magic potion that does:

In vwProjectViewModel I have:

```
 public List<SelectListItem> PageNumbers { get; set; }

 public int PageNumber { get; set; }
```

Here's the cshtml view snippet:

```
@model vwProjectViewModel

    <select name="PageNumber" id="PageNumber"
            asp-items='new SelectList(@Model.PageNumbers, 
                                      "Value", "Text", 
                                      Model.PageNumber)'>
    </select>
```

Here's a question: Why does adding **asp-for="PageNumber"** to the select tag break it so carelessly, making it no longer display the selected option?

Also, why does this simple syntax not display the selected option (didn't I see this here?):

`<select asp-for="PageNumber" asp-items="@Model.PageNumbers"></select>`

or

`<select asp-for="PageNumber" asp-items="Model.PageNumbers"></select>`

This also seems to display the selected option, but is considerably less elegant:

```
<select name="PageNumber" id="PageNumber">
@{
  @foreach (SelectListItem @item in @Model.PageNumbers)
  {
     @if (@Model.PageNumber.ToString() == @item.Value)
     {
          <option value="@item.Value" selected="selected">@item.Text</option>
     }
     else
     {
          <option value="@item.Value" >@item.Text</option>
     }
  }
}
</select>
```

Anyone care to shed some light on this quirky tag helper?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="PageNumber" asp-for="PageNumber" asp-items="Model.PageNumbers"> </select>
```

It will set selected if the value of `PageNumber`  if it has one that matches the value of a `SelectListItem`:

```
List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "1" });

selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "2" });
```

And :

```
vwProjectViewModel mymodel = new vwProjectViewModel();
mymodel.PageNumbers = new List<SelectListItem>();
mymodel.PageNumbers = selectListItems;
mymodel.PageNumber = 2;
```

Comment: As I said, I tried this but the selected option is not displayed. 
Anyway, why do we need id="PageNumber" if asp-for fills in ID and NAME for us?

<select asp-for="PageNumber" asp-items="Model.PageNumbers"> </select>

generates this: 

<select data-val="true" data-val-required="The PageNumber field is required." id="PageNumber" name="PageNumber"><option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
</select>

Note that I am not using razor pages with @Page at the top of the file, but rather cshtml razor MVC views.